# How to Include Non-Ordinal Dimensions in Clustering

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

Sorry about all of the questions on a particular topic.

But I'm also trying to think of adding a couple of non-cardinal dimensions to a set of existing numeric dimensions. What I essentially am looking for is to cluster on either **the same instances** of a value within one of these non-ordinal dimensions or (in a different dimension) to cluster on **different instances** of a value.

For instance, if I had added a dimension of color with 3 values `{Blue, Green, Red}` I would want to add weight towards common `Greens` in a cluster, but not give any more weighting what different color was in a cluster aka. a cluster with green and red would be the same as green and blue.

I am also interested in how to quantify the opposite dimension, that is trying to cluster on a high varying set of points with different color values.

The important thing here is that the extra dimensions have no cardinality to them, I only care to cluster on same instances, for one dimension, and different instances on another. This is just to supplement already existing cardinal, numeric dimensions.

Comment: Isn't that the same as having 3 new "standard" dimensions called *Blue, Green, Red* where for example a *red* data point would have the coordinates `(0,1,0)` (no blue, yes red, no green) and then do regular clustering on those?

Comment: @LumpN Yeah, that might work. Do you have an idea of what the opposite would be, to return a minimum distance for varying points rather than similar points?